# Using RF6886 Power Amplifier for VHF design

Tags: vhf

I want to use [RF 6886 power amplifier](http://www.rfmd.com/store/downloads/dl/file/id/29775/rf6886_data_sheet.pdf) for VHF band design. The datasheet doesn't mention VHF design specifications. Has anyone used the PA for VHF design? If yes then please share your designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The datasheet doesn't mention VHF design specifications.

VHF is 30-300 MHz. The Chip is only specified for 100 MHz upwards – so the lower part of VHF will definitely work very suboptimally.

So my first reaction would be: you're trying to use the wrong amplifier for VHF.

Anyway, assuming you're just considering the 100 – 300 MHz range: As far as I can read the data sheet, I'd say they expect a designer to have access to a network analyzer; the numbers they give for nominal complex input impedance for 430 MHz indicate that if you can design a 100 MHz - 300 MHz line with 50 Ohm impedance, then you should be fine :)

So, the main problem here is that you're in charge of designing a matching circuit, and that for a very wide band (100 - 300 MHz is as much bandwidth than the center frequency of 200 MHz! This means you need a wideband matching circuit). That won't be trivial. To be honest, you should ask their sales people for S-parameters at 100 – 300 MHz if this is your region of interest.

Generally, if you don't have access to calibrated microwave network analyzers, I'd simply estimate a matching inductance value from their 900 and 430 MHz examples, and try with their eval board; not like that you could get perfect matching with a single component over the whole 100-300 MHz band, anyways.